# Wifi stops working after going to specifi websites

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

Sometimes when browsing specific websites the wifi just stops working as if the router is blocking my computer from reconnecting.

I have tried service restart network-manager but nothing happens.

Note: other devices are able to connect to the router, so the router is fine.

What more could I provide that might aid understanding the issue at hand?

Comment: Why would `service restart` fix a router?

Comment: As the problem is not with the router since other devices stay connected. So what is causing this?

Comment: Are you sure it's wifi instead of browser or something else? Does Network Manager show a disconnection?  Does you syslog show anything happening at the disconnection time?

Comment: The network manager actually shows that its trying to connect. So yeah not the browser. I live in a country that were the ISP uses dpi to block users from using vpns and visiting certain websites. Do you think this might have anything to so with it?

Answer (score 0):

What fixed my issue here is setting the correct antenna on the network card using the following command

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"
```

and then `reboot`

Now I'm getting better signal and the mentioned issue is no more.